# forge.tabs tab closed on iOS when app is send to background

Tags: iphone, ios7, tabs, trigger.io

We are using trigger.io (2.1.0) in our mobile app and are opening the LinkedIn OAUTH dialog in a forge.tabs window (using forge.tabs 2.6). 
LinkedIn sends Authorisation Mails to Users when they authorise an app for the first time and the user has to enter an authorisation code he received via email in the view we opened in the forge.tab.

Unfortunately the tab in which we show the dialog is closed on iOS (iOS 7.0.4 here) when the app is sent to the background when the user switches to his mail app to get the code.

The user returns to the app and can't enter the code he just received. If he reopens the linked in authorisation dialog the code he just copied is not valid anymore (he is sent a new one).

How do we prevent the tab from being closed when the app is sent to the background?

Best regards, 
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official fix is in launchimage v2.3

Thank you to everyone who contributed to this question.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you want to use the launchimage module, the Trigger.io tab will always close when the app loses focus. See Richard's answer for more information.

A good workaround is to use Mobile Safari for the authentication process. After the authentication is finished you can make use of Trigger.io's URL scheme module to forward the user back to your app automatically.

Positive side-effect: the user might already be logged in on his Mobile Safari.

Comment: As mentioned above we found the source of this problem. I also added an issue to the github project for trigger.io-launchimage https://github.com/trigger-corp/trigger.io-launchimage/issues/2

Comment: Thank you for this in-depth analysis! I adjusted my answer.

Comment: Patrick can you explain how you open mobile safari and use the trigger.io URL scheme exactly to circumvent the problem?

Comment: What we do to completely avoid forge tabs: 1. Open mobile Safari with the authentication page. 2. Let the user finish the authentication flow (including email and whatelse). 3. Use `yourapp://auth/oauthkey` as the return url. 4. Your app automatically gets resumed when the URL in 3 is called, now you can retrieve the oauthkey from the URL and finish the login within the trigger app. Anything missing?

Answer (score 0):

We found the offender: The trigger launch image module seems to interfere with the trigger tabs module.

We stripped the project down to the last bits (load the tabs module only) and ended up with a plain html file which opens a trigger forge.tab when you click on a button.

Here the tab will persist even if you send the app to the background.

We found out that the trigger launch image module causes this behaviour - as soon as you add the module the trigger tabs vanish when the app is backgrounded.

We can confirm that the launch image module closes all modal dialogs when the app is backgrounded - we forked the module and will try to fix it.

Comment: Any news on that fix yet?

Comment: I communicated the problem to trigger.io and asked if the fix would cause problems. I got the answer that it is okay how i implemented it. In order to fix it you have to remove the showing of the splash screen on backgrounding the app and remove the dismissal when the app returns to the foreground.

Comment: Fix: 
I removed the hideLaunchimage call from applicationDidEnterBackground and the showLaunchimage call from applicationWillResume.